# HTML drop down javascript help needed

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML drop down

```
 <select>
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

    <select>
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
```

Now, If I Select volvo from first drop down and b from second dropdown and then I change to Audi in the first dropdown, I want the value of second drop down to show Please Select instead of b (selected previously) using javascript

PS: I am new to Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
  <select onChange="document.getElementById('secondOption').selectedIndex = 0;">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

    <select id="secondOption">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the index supposing you've two `<select>`

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
selects[0].onchange = function(){
   selects[1].selectedIndex = 0;
}
```